# Query resullts not looping

Tags: php, mysqli

I have set up a mysqli query on my database. I have been trying to loop the results to show multipe rows and have followed numerous tutorials on how to do so. However, I am still only getting one row appearing on the page. Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

```
$query2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM journeys WHERE id = $id");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

if($count == 0) {
    $journeys = 'You have no future journeys.';
}
else{
    $result = $con->query($query2);
    while ( $row = $query2->fetch_assoc() ) {

    $journeys = "{$row['origin']}-{$row['destination']}<br />{$row['date']}<br />{$row['hour']}:{$row['minute']}";
}

    }
```

Comment: $result = $con->query($query2); this line contains the error. you need to comment this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$journeys = "{$row['origin']}-{$row['destination']}<br />{$row['date']}<br />{$row['hour']}:{$row['minute']}";
```

You assign to `$journeys` on every loop iteration, which replaces the old contents, hence `$journeys` will contain only the data from the last row in the query. You need to add these to an array, for example

```
while(...)
    $journeys[] = "{$row['origin']}-{$row['destination']}<br />{$row['date']}<br />{$row['hour']}:{$row['minute']}";
```

Note that the empty array subscript in an assignment simply assigns to the next available index.

Then iterate over the array to print it, e.g.

```
foreach($journeys as $journey)
    echo $journey;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to run `$result = $con->query($query2);`  again as $query2 already has the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM journeys WHERE id = $id");

//chck the query execution status
if ($query2) 
{
    //print error message
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
}
else
{
    //get the count of the result
    $count = $query2->num_rows;

    if($count == 0) 
    {
        $journeys = 'You have no future journeys.';
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array();

        //process each row
        while ( $row = $query2->fetch_assoc() )
        {
            //display the result
            echo "{$row['origin']}-{$row['destination']}<br />{$row['date']}<br />{$row['hour']}:{$row['minute']}";

           // dumb into array
           // $data[] = "{$row['origin']}-{$row['destination']}<br />{$row['date']}<br />{$row['hour']}:{$row['minute']}";
        }

                //print the result
        //print_r($data);

    }
}
```